# C# WCF Contract Returns List<object> for Derived KnownType

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, interface, datacontract

Hello,
I have a WCF service which has a wrapper class:

```
[DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(List<IFNStatusViewModel>))]
    public class ResolvedProcessModel
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<IProcessViewModel> ResolvedModel { get; set; }
    }
```

As the list of `IFNStatusViewModel` inherits from `IProcessViewModel`.

The data is being passed but the problem is it returns from the contract as `List<object>` instead of `List<IFNStatusViewModel>` as shown below:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Collections.Generic.List<object> ResolvedModel {
            get {
                return this.ResolvedModelField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.ResolvedModelField, value) != true)) {
                    this.ResolvedModelField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("ResolvedModel");
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to explicitly specify the class to serialize as `List<IFNStatusViewModel>` in the recieving side of contract?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] that includes all necessary type definitions including samples for `IFNStatusViewModel`, `IProcessViewModel` and so on?  It's not even clear from your question whether these are interfaces or classes.

Comment: Absent a [mcve] I can only guess that `[KnownType(typeof(List<IFNStatusViewModel>))]` should be `[KnownType(typeof(IFNStatusViewModel))]`.  I.e. the missing known type is `IFNStatusViewModel` not `List<IFNStatusViewModel>`.  But I can't say for sure without a concrete example that reproduces the problem.